# print python stack trace without exception being raised

Tags: python, debugging, stack-trace

Something is happening with one of my class's instance variables. I want to make the variable a property, and whenever it is accessed I want to print out the stack trace of all the code leading up to that point, so I can see where it's being messed with. How do I print out the stack trace when no exception has been raised? I know if there is an exception I can do something like `traceback.format_tb(sys.exc_info()[2])`.

Also what might be useful is to print only the last 3-4 levels, since the first few are probably not going to be that interesting.

Answer (score 140, accepted):

[`traceback.print_stack()`](http://docs.python.org/library/traceback.html#traceback.print_stack):

```
>>> def f():
...   def g():
...     traceback.print_stack()
...   g()
...
>>> f()
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in f
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in g
```

Edit: You can also use [extract_stack](http://docs.python.org/library/traceback.html#traceback.extract_stack), take a slice (e.g. `stack[5:]` for exclude the first 5 levels) and use [format_list](http://docs.python.org/library/traceback.html#traceback.format_list) to get a print-ready stacktrace (`'\n'.join(traceback.format_list(...))`)

Comment: Thanks for the edit, it helped me with [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16589622/321973) for a very general `full_stack()` function!

Answer (score 29):

Instead of printing to stdout, if you need a string to pass to a logger you can use:

```
''.join(traceback.format_stack())
```

Note, that traceback.format_stack() returns the stacktrace as a formatted list of strings, so you can slice it anyway you want. To get the last few elements of the stacktrace you could do:

```
''.join(traceback.format_stack()[-N:])
```

Where N is the number of levels you are interested in.