# How can I get the traceback object ( sys.exc_info()[2] , same as sys.exc_traceback ) as a string?

Tags: python, string, data-conversion, traceback, string-conversion

I have a function which catches all exceptions, and I want to be able to get the traceback as a string within this function.

So far this is not working:

```
def handle_errors(error_type, error_message, error_traceback):
    """catch errors"""
    import traceback
    error = {}
    error['type'] = error_type.__name__
    error['message'] = str(error_message)
    error['file'] = os.path.split(error_traceback.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename)[1]
    error['line'] = error_traceback.tb_lineno
    error['traceback'] = repr(traceback.print_tb(error_traceback))
    ### finalise error handling and exit ###

sys.excepthook = handle_errors
```

It's the `error['traceback']` line which is wrong. Do i even need to use the `traceback` module?

As per [this other vaguely similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13210436/get-full-traceback?rq=1), I have tried:

```
error['traceback'] = repr(error_traceback.print_exc())
```

...but this gives an error:

```
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xxxxxxxxxxx", line 54, in handle_errors
    error['traceback'] = repr(error_traceback.print_exc())
AttributeError: 'traceback' object has no attribute 'print_exc'
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get full traceback](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13210436/get-full-traceback)

Comment: that question is not applicable. i will update my question explaining why

Comment: Hello. See my answer please. Why did you wrote that your question isn't applicable ?

Comment: @eyquem because [that other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13210436/get-full-traceback) is not about capturing a traceback within an excepthook function. the excepthook function provides a traceback frame to query (`error_traceback`) but that other question does not address how to use this frame.

Comment: I don't understand what you say because of _"that other question"_ ? Which **other** question ??

Comment: Besides, I remark something I didn't until now: in the definition of ``handle_errors``, the reference _error['traceback']_ is assigned to repr() of ``traceback.print_tb(error_traceback))`` while the account of the exception says it is repr() of ``error_traceback.print_exc())``

Comment: to see the other question i am talking about, please click on the link-words 'that other question' in my previous comment. its the one which you have put `This question may already have an answer here:` at the top of my original post

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use [`traceback.format_tb()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html#traceback.format_tb) instead of `print_tb()` to get the formatted stack trace (as a list of lines):

```
error['traceback'] = ''.join(traceback.format_tb(error_traceback))
```

`print_tb()` directly *prints* the traceback, that's why you get `None` as a result (that's the default for any Python function that doesn't return anything explicitely).

Comment: Your answer led me to the precise solution.

Answer (score 0):

> `traceback.format_exc([limit])`
>   This is `like print_exc(limit)` but
>   returns a string instead of printing to a file.
>
> New in version 2.4.

```
error['traceback'] = traceback.format_exc(error_traceback)
```

Comment: This does not work due to reasons pointed out by Lukas G. in the accepted answer that was posted earlier than yours.