# Print stacktrace with variables values on uncaught exception in Flask

Tags: python, debugging, logging, exception, stack-trace

I use next code to caught uncaught exceptions in my Flask app:

```
@app.errorhandler(Exception)
def uncaught_exception_handler(error):
    if not app.config['DEVELOPMENT']:
        app.logger.error(error, exc_info=True)
    else:
        raise error

    return 'Internal Server Error', 500
```

How can I add extra information about values of variables in each stack frame to my log file? It looks like `cgitb` is doing desired things but it print error info to stdout or to a file and not returned it as a string. I know that it is possible to do what I want with `inspect` and `traceback` modules but as this is Python I think that there already exists appropriate solution for such problem.

Comment: You can dump the `locals()` or `globals()` should you need to.

Comment: And what about not current stack frame? Should I call locals() for every frame manually?

Comment: what do you mean by "not current"? what are your expected **variables** you want to capture?

Comment: When exception is raised (exactly at that moment) program has call stack with depth n. Current frame for me is that frame at which exception is raised. Frame of caller (function that called function that raised an exception) has own stack frame too (depth n-1). And so on. And I want to obtain values of each local variable within every frames. Exactly like cgitb doing that in [this example](http://pymotw.com/2/cgitb/).

Comment: Alright I see what you mean, basically you want the full stack, you may be interested in this [SO Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13210436/get-full-traceback)

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you want something like this:
https://github.com/ActiveState/code/blob/3b27230f418b714bc9a0f897cb8ea189c3515e99/recipes/Python/52215_Get_more/recipe-52215.py