# Get full traceback with sys.exc_info()

Tags: python, traceback

It seems like the traceback returned `sys.exc_info()` contains only the frames from inside the `try:` block where you caught the exception from. Is there a way to get the full traceback?

To clarify, I want to get the traceback so that `traceback.print_exc()` prints the same, *full* traceback every time it is called in this snippet (just as the last call and the `sys.excepthook` printed in the end):

```
def a():
  try:
    raise ValueError
  except:
    traceback.print_exc()
    raise

def b():
  try:
    a()
  except:
    traceback.print_exc()
    raise

try:
  b()
except:
  traceback.print_exc()
  raise
```

The output for this snippet is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 403, in a
    raise ValueError
ValueError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 410, in b
    a()
  File "test.py", line 403, in a
    raise ValueError
ValueError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 417, in <module>
    b()
  File "test.py", line 410, in b
    a()
  File "test.py", line 403, in a
    raise ValueError
ValueError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 417, in <module>
    b()
  File "test.py", line 410, in b
    a()
  File "test.py", line 403, in a
    raise ValueError
ValueError
```

Comment: The best solution I'm aware of is to combine the results of `traceback.extract_tb` and `traceback.extract_stack`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a complete exception stack trace in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6086976/how-to-get-a-complete-exception-stack-trace-in-python)