# java's printStackTrace() equivalent in python

Tags: java, python

In python except block, I want to print the error message but I don't want the program to stop executing, I understand that I have to do something like this

```
try:
    1/0
except: 
    print errorMessage
```

In the except part, I am looking to put something like java's `printStackTrace()`

Comment: To print the stack trace without causing an exception to be raised, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925248/print-python-stack-trace-without-exception-being-raised

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Take a look at [`traceback.print_exc()`](http://docs.python.org/library/traceback.html#traceback.print_exc) and the rest of the [`traceback`](http://docs.python.org/library/traceback.html) module.

```
import traceback

try:
    1/0
except:
    print '>>> traceback <<<'
    traceback.print_exc()
    print '>>> end of traceback <<<'
```

There are some more examples [towards the end of the `traceback` documentation page](http://docs.python.org/library/traceback.html#traceback-examples).

Answer (score 3):

If you really just want the error message, you can just print the error (notice how I specify the exception in the except—that’s good practice, see [pep8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations) for recommendations on catching errors):

```py
try:
    1/0
except Exception as e:
    print e
```

However, if you want the stackstrace, as @Eddified said in a comment, you can use the example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925248/print-python-stack-trace-without-exception-being-raised). Or more specifically for your case:

```py
import traceback
try:
    1/0
except Exception as e:
    print e
    traceback.print_stack()
```

Comment: Just a headsup, [print_stack](http://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html#traceback.print_stack) merely prints the stack from whatever line of code you're at, while [print_exc() prints the exception's stack trace](http://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html#traceback.print_exception).

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `logging.exception` from the `logging` module. It will print the current exception's stacktrace into the default logger as a message of severity `ERROR`.

Link: http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.exception